# How to change default selected item in a TabbedPage?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I want to change the deafult selected tab to another one using a binding command, but without using codebehind. Here is my code:

```
<TabbedPage ...
        x:Class="XCMDEMO.Views.ShellView"
        xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:XCMDEMO.Views"
        SelectedItem="Second">
<ContentPage Title="Tab 1" x:Name="First" />
<ContentPage Title="Tab 2" x:Name="Second" BackgroundColor="Red"/>
<ContentPage Title="Tab 3" />
```

I've tried to bind context to page itself, but the are no properties like First or Second :

```
<TabbedPage SelectedItem = {Binding Second}>
<TabbedPage.BindingContext>
    <Views:ShellView/>
</TabbedPage.BindingContext>
```

Need to be similar to this :

```
    public ShellView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.SelectedItem = Second; 
    }
```

Comment: Isn't SelectedItem going to be of type contentpage rather than string?

Comment: Yes, it should be a content page, just to show what tab is intended to be,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not set SelectedItem to a string.

So remove

```
 SelectedItem="Second".
```

And whatever this.SelectedItem = Second; is supposed to do as well.

Bind SelectedIndex mode=twoway to a public property int in whatever your viewmodel is.
Implement inotifypropertychanged in your viewmodel.
Set that property to 1 initially.

Comment: The purpose of my question is because previewer don't show the selected item, and the code behind methods aren't shown in the previewere as well and I don't want to use a view model at this stage.

Comment: Seems that there are no reasons to do it from XAML. I've tried to debug it and discovered that even if SelectedItem is set it's not displayng, not sure why.